# ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR in sails.js using waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

I know there are similar questions but they haven't help me.

I've got an error when trying to use .find() method on model: product2 
(.query() method is working )

I was trying to find out how to get more verbose output from database, but with failure.

```
{
"error": "E_UNKNOWN",
"status": 500,
"summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
  "raw": {
  "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
  "errno": 1054,
  "sqlState": "42S22",
  "index": 0
}
}%
```

my model "Product2.js"

```
  module.exports = {

  connection:'someMysqlServer',
  migration:'safe',
  tableName:'NUTR_DATA',
  attributes:{
    id:{
      columnName:'Nutr_No',
      primaryKey:true,
      type:'string'


    }


  }
};
```

routes.js

```
module.exports.routes{
'GET /select':'Product2Controller.select'

};
```

Product2Controller.js

```
module.exports = {
  select:function(req,res){
        Product2.find({limit:10}).exec(function(err, results) {
            if (err){res.serverError(err)}
            else{res.json(results)};
        });
    }
};
```

database schema

```
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| NDB_No        | varchar(5)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Nutr_No       | varchar(3)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Nutr_Val      | decimal(13,3) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Num_Data_Ptr  | decimal(10,0) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Std_Error     | decimal(11,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Src_Cd        | varchar(2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Deriv_cd      | varchar(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Ref_NDB_No    | varchar(5)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Add_Nutr_Mark | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Num_Studies   | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Min           | decimal(13,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Max           | decimal(13,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| DF            | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Low_EB        | decimal(13,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Up_EB         | decimal(13,3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Stat_cmd      | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| AddMod_Date   | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| CC            | varchar(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Comment: There is no `NutrDesc` column in your table.

Comment: Yes, my bad this was because I'had testing various tables. But it not working even with only id attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. The problem was not setted

```
autoCreatedAt: false,
autoUpdatedAt: false
```

i hadn't see that my ide actually give me more verbose output then curl. Maybe it would be better if errors would be placed under calming picture of boat and info about lifted server :P

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that you're defining your own primary key field, but Waterline is still atuomatically adding its own `id` field.  You can turn off this behavior by adding `autoPK: false` to your model configuration.  Docs for `autoPK` are [here](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html?q=autopk).